# How to select identical rows from a pandas dataframe along with null

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to pandas and I'm having problem with row selections from dataframe.

Following is my DataFrame :

```
 Index Column1 Column2 Column3       Column4  Column5
   0   1234    500     NEWYORK       NY       NaN
   1   5678    700     AUSTIN        TX       5678956010  
   2   1234    300     NEWYORKCITY   NY       NaN
   3   8910    235     RICHMOND      FL       8484883666
   4   8910    250     AUSTIN        TX       8484883666
   5   5324    150     AUSTIN        TX       NaN
```

1.) I want to select rows that are having same values in Column5. So the output dataframe should contain rows with index 0,2,3 and 4. Note that two rows with NaN in Column 5 should be selected only if their Column1 value is same(example. rows with index 0 and 2).

Can any one help me with a step-by-step procedure for this custom selection. Thanks in advance...

Comment: I've tried df[column5].duplicated(keep=False) & df[column5].isnull() = False and few other combinations, but I'm not getting the expected output.

Comment: Can you show the desired output?

Comment: If in `column1` for row `4` is changed `8910` to `123` need return `0,2,3,4` rows too?

Comment: yes ... exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need 2 sets of conditions - for `NaN`s in `Column5` and for non NaNs and last chain them by `|` (or):

```
m1 = df['Column1'].duplicated(keep=False) & df['Column5'].isnull()
m2 = df['Column5'].duplicated(keep=False) & df['Column5'].notnull()

df = df[m1 | m2]
print (df)
   Index  Column1  Column2      Column3 Column4       Column5
0      0     1234      500      NEWYORK      NY           NaN
2      2     1234      300  NEWYORKCITY      NY           NaN
3      3     8910      235     RICHMOND      FL  8.484884e+09
4      4     8910      250       AUSTIN      TX  8.484884e+09
```

Detail:

```
print (m1)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool

print (m2)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
Name: Column5, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Output is same as the one you've printed.... but when I tried same thing it is selecting row with index 5(which also has NaN in column 5) as well... Rows having NaN in column 5 should only be slected if their column1 value is same... can you suggest any custom condition for this??

Comment: Also if two rows have same  Column 5 value and it is not null and if their column1 value is different then i want to select those rows as well.

Comment: Your solution works for the perfectly for the second case.. but fails when there is a NaN in Column5 and respective Column1 value is different(It is also selecting row with index 5). Can you please re-check??

Comment: I think no, check `print (m1)`, there is only `True` for `0,2`. `last 5` row is `False`

Comment: ok... ok.. got it.. sorry for the trouble..Now it's working fine.. Thanks a lot.. Cheers

Comment: No problem, testing is super and necessary ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use:

```
df[df.duplicated(['Column1', 'Column5'], keep=False)
#Index Column1 Column2 Column3       Column4  Column5
#  0   1234    500     NEWYORK       NY       NaN
#  2   1234    300     NEWYORKCITY   NY       NaN
#  3   8910    235     RICHMOND      FL       8484883666
#  4   8910    250     AUSTIN        TX       8484883666
```

Comment: I've tried this one... what if i want to select rows which are having same Column5 value but different Column1 value.. In this case i dont want rows having NaNs in Column5 and different values in Column1